# Authorities not loaded in Spring Security with JWT token and Spring Boot 3

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

I am developing a Java service using JDK 17, Spring Boot 3, and Spring Security 6.0.3. The service is an API that requires validation of a JWT token using a public key.

I have the following security configuration in SecurityConfig.java:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtDecoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
    public static final String ADMIN = "ROLE_ADMIN";

    private static final String[] AUTH_WHITELIST = {
        "/actuator/**",
    };

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http, JwtDecoder jwtDecoder) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf().disable()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
            .formLogin().disable()
            .authorizeHttpRequests(requests -> requests
                .requestMatchers(AUTH_WHITELIST).permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/api/test/**").hasAnyAuthority(ADMIN)
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            )
            .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 -> oauth2.jwt(jwt -> {
                jwt.decoder(jwtDecoder);
            }));

        return http.build();
    }
}
```

In addition, the AppConfig.java class contains the following code:

```
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtDecoder;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.NimbusJwtDecoder;

import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.*;

@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AppConfig {
    private final RsaKeyProperties rsaKeys;

    @Bean
    JwtDecoder jwtDecoder() {
        return NimbusJwtDecoder.withPublicKey(rsaKeys.publicKey()).build();
    }
}
```

The problem I'm facing is that Spring Security is not loading the authorities as expected. The following log message shows an authenticated token, but the "Granted Authorities" are empty:

> 2023-05-15T16:26:39.048+02:00 DEBUG 74733 --- [nio-8080-exec-3]
> o.s.s.o.s.r.a.JwtAuthenticationProvider  : Authenticated token
> 2023-05-15T16:26:39.048+02:00 DEBUG 74733 --- [nio-8080-exec-3]
> .s.r.w.a.BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter : Set SecurityContextHolder
> to JwtAuthenticationToken
> [Principal=org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.Jwt@d70a35df,
> Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true,
> Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1,
> SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[]]

I have even tried using a custom Converter in AppConfig.java to convert the claims and add the authorities, but the issue persists. Here is the relevant code from AppConfig.java:

```
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtDecoder;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.NimbusJwtDecoder;

import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.*;

@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AppConfig {
    private final RsaKeyProperties rsaKeys;

    @Bean
    JwtDecoder jwtDecoder() {
        NimbusJwtDecoder jwtDecoder = NimbusJwtDecoder.withPublicKey(rsaKeys.publicKey()).build();
        jwtDecoder.setClaimSetConverter(getClaimConverter());
        return jwtDecoder;
    }

    private Converter<Map<String, Object>, Map<String, Object>> getClaimConverter() {
        return claims -> {
            Map<String, Object> mutableClaims = new HashMap<>(claims);

            // Convert 'exp' and 'iat' fields to Instant
            if (claims.containsKey("exp")) {
                Date expDate = (Date) claims.get("exp");
                Instant expInstant = expDate.toInstant();
                mutableClaims.put("exp", expInstant);
            }

            if (claims.containsKey("iat")) {
                Date iatDate = (Date) claims.get("iat");
                Instant iatInstant = iatDate.toInstant();
                mutableClaims.put("iat", iatInstant);
            }

            // Hardcoded authorities for testing
            List<String> authorities = List.of("ROLE_ADMIN");
            mutableClaims.put("authorities", authorities);

            System.out.println("Claims: " + claims);
            System.out.println("Mutable claims: " + mutableClaims);

            return mutableClaims;
        };
    }
}
```

Despite these modifications, the "Granted Authorities" in the authentication token are still empty. As a result, I receive a 403 Forbidden response with the following message:

> www-authenticate: Bearer error="insufficient_scope",
> error_description="The request requires higher privileges than
> provided by the access token.",
> error_uri="https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6750#section-3.1" I have
> also tested with hardcoding the authorities to ensure that the token
> format is not the issue. However, the authorities are still not
> properly loaded.

I would greatly appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to resolve this issue and ensure that the authorities are correctly loaded in Spring Security based on the provided token.

Thank you in advance for your help!

---

Edit 1

Token example

```
{
  "sub": "admin@example.com",
  "iss": "self",
  "exp": 1684164375,
  "token_type": "access_token",
  "iat": 1684160775,
  "authorities": [
    "ROLE_TEST",
    "ROLE_ADMIN",
  ]
}
```

Comment: this is documented here in https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/resource-server/jwt.html#oauth2resourceserver-jwt-authorization-extraction in the spring security documentation here is a fully documented example with code, and a large blogpost about how to do what you want to do https://github.com/Tandolf/spring-security-jwt-demo

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I implemented a new class to convert granted authorities:

```
public class JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter implements Converter<Jwt, Collection<GrantedAuthority>> {

    @Override
    public Collection<GrantedAuthority> convert(Jwt jwt) {
        List<Map<String, String>> authorities = jwt.getClaim("authorities");

        return authorities.stream()
                .map(authority -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(authority.get("authority")))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

Then I use it in SecurityFilterChain:

```
                .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 -> oauth2.jwt(jwt -> {
                    jwt.decoder(jwtDecoder);
                    jwt.jwtAuthenticationConverter(jwtAuthenticationConverter());
                }));
```

Answer (score 0):

With `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server` dependency you can also do that with out-of-box [JwtAuthenticationConverter](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/main/oauth2/oauth2-resource-server/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/server/resource/authentication/JwtAuthenticationConverter.java) class by just defining an additional `@Bean`:

```java
@Bean
public JwtAuthenticationConverter jwtAuthenticationConverter() {
    final JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter grantedAuthoritiesConverter = new JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter();
    grantedAuthoritiesConverter.setAuthoritiesClaimName("authorities"); // defaults to "scope" or "scp"
    grantedAuthoritiesConverter.setAuthorityPrefix(""); // defaults to "SCOPE_"

    final JwtAuthenticationConverter jwtAuthenticationConverter = new JwtAuthenticationConverter();
    jwtAuthenticationConverter.setJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter(grantedAuthoritiesConverter);
    return jwtAuthenticationConverter;
}
```

With it you don't need to additionally configure your `JwtDecoder` and set any converters manually to a security filter chain config.
This converter supports authorities claim as array and as string, in case of string representation consider defining delimiter using [`setAuthoritiesClaimDelimiter()`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/main/oauth2/oauth2-resource-server/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/server/resource/authentication/JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter.java#L91) method, default is `" "` (single space character).